# ¿Como convertir un dato de tipo string a int(float) y sacar promedio?

Tags: sql

tengo un query que me arroja resultados de tipo string, Ese dato lo convierto a tipo entero(aclaro que puedo también convertirlo a float) y después quiero que sobre ese mismo me entrege el resultado promediado.

Espero y me puedan ayudar.

este es el Query

```
select cedis,
           convert(int, (count(clientes_con_rechazo))) Totales
        from tmpcalculo
        group by cedis
```

Este es el resultado que actualmente me arroja

```
cedis   Totales
Celaya  1437
```

Ejemplo de como me lo arrojaría.

```
cedis   Totales
Celaya  10.45
```

Comment: No entiendo bien. Cuál es la necesidad de convertir el `count`  a `int`?, ese resultado ya entrega un `int`

Comment: Hola, si no es mucha molestia podría reeditar tu pregunta para que tenga los estilos adecuados? Jeje

Comment: Mis disculpas, el dato que me arroja, proviene de un sp, extremadamente largo. Se los puedo agregar. El query te arroja un count, por que primero se cuentan los registros, ese dato te lo entrega en varchar, después se convierte a int (tal vez se necesite a float por los decimales) y sobre ese resultado se requiere promediar. Espero me haya explicado.

Comment: @Lamak me quitaste palabra de los dedos... es la 1ª vez que veo el intento de convertir a entero un entero. Por otra parte, generalmente el propósito de la BD es almacenar los datos según su tipo, **los enteros como enteros, los strings como strings...** etc. Y si recoges los datos en una aplicación o programa, mejor **haz las conversiones y formatea los datos en el destino, no en el orígen**. Es como cuando compras algo, te gusta que venga envuelto en su caja, todo nuevo... y tener el placer de abrirlo y desempaquetarlo. Si te lo mandan abierto, no, no, no... Pasa lo mismo con los datos.

Comment: No puedes simplemente arreglar el sp para que entregue el `count` como entero (que es lo que debería hacer en primer lugar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver si he entendido lo que quieres.

Tienes una tabla con dos campos de tipo cadena. En el campo clientes_con_rechazo tienes almacenado un valor entero en formato de cadena.
Quieres sacar el promedio de los valores de este campo agrupados por el valor del campo cedis.

Si es así, y deseas que el resultado te salga con decimales, deberías convertir el valor de la columna a float y calcular el promedia con la función AVG agrupando por el campo cedis:

```
SELECT cedis, AVG(CONVERT(float, clientes_con_rechazo))
FROM tmpcalculo
GROUP BY cedis
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesito, disculpas por no darme a entender. Estoy intentando tu solución, pero me manda error. Me dice que no la puede convertir "varchar to float" pero tu solución es la respuesta.

Comment: Comprueba que los valores del campo clientes_con_rechazo sean números. Si no tendrás errores de conversión.

Comment: Es lo que les decía, ese query me arroja los resultados en varchar, lo estoy convirtiendo a float, después de convertirlo realizo el promedio

Comment: Sí pero si te está dando un error de conversión será porque alguno de los valores del campo clientes_con_rechazo tiene algún carácter no numérico

Comment: Los datos los arroja como varchar, pero vere la forma de arreglarlo Gracias de nuevo a todos.

Comment: @Ric_hc, recuerda que si esta respuesta soluciona tu pregunta, puedes [aceptarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.